# How to define public classes in Less?

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to define generic classes for my website in a file called "generic.less" and it's correctly linked in the `head` in my HTML file. This Less file contains:

```
/****GENERIC CLASSES****/
/**********************/
.border-box{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;}
.unselectable{-moz-user-select:none; -khtml-user-select:none; -webkit-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;}
.grayscale{-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); filter:grayscale(100%);}
.fullcenter{top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; position:absolute;}
```

And then I'm trying to inherit these classes from different "less" files but it won't work. I'm guessing that Less takes the classes as private classes defined in the same "less" file (sorry for my Java interpretation).

Is there any way I can define those classes so I can inherit them from other Less file? That way I don't have to duplicate the classes for each new class file.

My HTML `<head>` element looks like this:

```
<!-- STYLE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="<?echo $path_styles;?>generic.less"> <!-- Generic classes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="<?echo $path_styles;?>index.less">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="<?echo $path_styles;?>bio.less">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="<?echo $path_styles;?>discografia.less">
```

Comment: How did you try to *inherit*? Did you `import` the generic.less file in the other .less files?

Comment: @Harry I was importing including the class selector reference like a property inside another class. I just tried to import the generic file and it worked, it was so simple. I thought it would be enough just to declaring the classes before inheriting them but it's logical that I need to import the file because we are talking about "pre-processing". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LESS file doesn't know about other LESS files when compiled.
In each of your LESS files (except `generic.less` itself, of course), you can **[import](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature)** your generic file with `@import`. As it'd output many times the CSS of this file, you should add the **[option `(reference)`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference)**: file is imported so variables and mixins are known to the rest of the file import-ing it but it isn't output.

```
@import (reference) "generic.less"
```

Sidenote: are you using `less.js`, even in development? Server-side tools like `gulp-less` or Prepros (v4 was free software) are much convenient and fast imho.

Comment: Thanks! Got it now! In regard to the sidenote, I'm using "less preprocessor" linking the "less.js" javascript file because I just started with CSS preprocessors and I find that method way more simple. So, do you recommend me to install it server-side? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you see from the [LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-mixins), it's very simple to inherit classes, to use them on a separate file you just need to `@import` them to the main LESS file (to the beginning) http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature

```
.bordered {
  border-top: dotted 1px black;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}
```

And we want to use these properties inside other rule-sets. Well, we just have to drop in the name of the class where we want the properties, like so:

```
#menu a {
  color: #111;
  .bordered;
}

.post a {
  color: red;
  .bordered;
}
```

We can also use functions the same way..

```
.transition(@transition) {
    -webkit-transition: @transition;
    -moz-transition: @transition;
    -o-transition: @transition;
    transition: @transition;
}
.opacity(@opacity) {
    opacity: @opacity / 100;
    filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacity})";
}

a {
    .transition(all 0.4s);
    &:hover {
        .opacity(70);
    }
}
```